# Tales of Symphonia chronicles additional missables?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Are there any new things in *Tales of Symphonia* in *Tales of Symphonia Chronicles* that are missable beyond those of the original gamecube release?  Is there anything missable that was added in this PS3 version over what was missable in the gamecube version?

I know what is missable in the gamecube version so there is no need to detail those. I am only interested in the missables that are different from those of the gamecube version.  Thanks!

Comment: Since it's an hd version of the PS2 version, [the differences between the gamecube and ps2 versions](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/561316-tales-of-symphonia/faqs/32765) seem relevant.

Comment: You can miss a few titles if you never played Tales of Graces f or Tales of Xillia on your PSN account. The game grants you titles (which are really just costumes) based on whether you have a set of trophies for either of those two games. Since those are the only 2 US Tales of games on the PS3 (at this time), playing those will grant you costumes from Tales of Xillia 2 and Tales of Vesparia as well. I wouldn't call them missables so much, but they do count toward your title count and you earn trophies for earning titles... so you can earn those trophies quicker ;)

Comment: Some titles effect your stat growth when you level, although those are iirc mostly not the cosmetic ones, so it's possible that missing those bonus titles could have an effect on gameplay.